# Is the Facebook user ID accessible to an app without authorization?

Tags: facebook

I'm writing a simple survey app for Facebook (it is just a form that asks what books people read). I don't want any information about the users (except what they enter in the survey), I don't want to post to their wall etc., but I would like their Facebook user ID, so I can recognize duplicates.

If I allow the users to use the app without any authorization, can I still "see" their Facebook user ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without authorization?- unfortunately **you can't**!

The only way to query for the **current** user is `/me`- and it requires an access token and for the access token the user needs to authorize your app.

If you don't want to do this to make sure user don't take your survey due to this- minute chances are there that this will happen since each and every app uses the authorization. And you're not requesting anything extra but just the basic info. So, I think you should implement this if you want something unique of that user!

But if you don't want to implement just to avoid going through the docs and all, Ill provide you the very small code you need to get the user-id-

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({
     appId      : '{app-id}', 
     status     : true, 
     cookie     : true,
     xfbml      : true  
  }); 

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
      // save this uid
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      login();    
    } else {
      login();
    }
 });
};  

(function(d){
  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];     
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
  js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
  ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));

function login(){
 FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
      FB.api('/me', function(response) {
          var uid= response.id;
          // save uid here
      });
   } else {
     // user did not authorized your app, handle accordingly (continue as guest /ask for auth again by refreshing the page)
   }
 });
}
```

(just replace the `{app-id}` with your app-id.)

Answer (score 0):

No, the user must have authorized your app to have his `user_id` in the [signed_request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/)

Answer (score 0):

@Plamen is right... But what I don't understand is that you want to let the user manually enter some information which is probably already available via API to some extent.

For example

1. You could gather the liked books via the `/{user_id}/books` (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/books/) endpoint
2. Use the Book OpenGraph object (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/books.book)
3. Use the books.reads OpenGrpah action (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/books.reads/)

Comment: Thank you. I'm not interested in the liked books, but in other aspects of reading habit (genres, number of books per week, time spent with books per day, etc.). Stuff that's not on FB.